# How to index a python df for mutiple values

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a df:

```
     ccy    tenor    entry    exit
0    EUR    3m3m       1       3           
1    GBP    6m3m       2       1           
2    JPY    1y1y       4       2        
3    EUR    2y1y       2       5           
4    GBP    9m3m       1       2        
5    AUD    6m3m3m     1       5        
6    JPY    2y1y       3       4
```

A simple question, but im struggling a touch. How do I subset the df for:
a) tenors of 1y1y and 2y1y (I.e. anything ending with 1y)
b) tenors of 3m3m, 6m3m, 9m3m, 6m3m3m (I.e. anything ending with 3m)

```
df[df.tenor == '1y1y']
```

for a), the above gives me 1y1y, but I need to select multiple tenors

Thanks

expected output for a)

```
     ccy    tenor    entry    exit          
2    JPY    1y1y       4       2        
3    EUR    2y1y       2       5                 
6    JPY    2y1y       3       4
```

expected output for b)

```
     ccy    tenor    entry    exit
0    EUR    3m3m       1       3           
1    GBP    6m3m       2       1                    
4    GBP    9m3m       1       2        
5    AUD    6m3m3m     1       5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) or [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html):

```
df1 = df[df.tenor.str.endswith('1y')]
#alternative with regex $ for end of string
#df1 = df[df.tenor.str.contains('1y$')]
print (df1)
   ccy tenor  entry  exit
2  JPY  1y1y      4     2
3  EUR  2y1y      2     5
6  JPY  2y1y      3     4

df2 = df[df.tenor.str.endswith('3m')]
#alternative with regex $ for end of string
#df2 = df[df.tenor.str.contains('3m$')]
print (df2)
   ccy   tenor  entry  exit
0  EUR    3m3m      1     3
1  GBP    6m3m      2     1
4  GBP    9m3m      1     2
5  AUD  6m3m3m      1     5
```